# VB/Regex: Replace character with conditions on preceding and following characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to turn any zero that is not preceded by a space and zero or arbitrary many numbers and not followed by zero or an arbitrary amount of numbers and a + or - into a dot.

So far, I've managed to replace every zero not followed by zero or an arbitrary amount of numbers and a + or - with a dot, using this:

```
Str1 = " 0 0c000c0+c0-c 10c0c"
Str2 = Regex.Replace(Str1, "(?!\s+\d*)0(?!\d*[\+\-])", ".")
```

This returns " . .c...c0+c0-c 1.c.c", so the last part is working, the first one isn't.

I want that zeros are replaced if the are following this pattern:

```
<stuff><not a space followed by numbers>0<other numbers not followed by a plus or minus><more stuff>
```

Examples:

```
" 100c" >>> " 100c"
"c00c10+" >>> "c..c10+"
" 0 0cc0c0-" >>> " 0 0cc.c0-"
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Is the expected result `<SPACE>0 0c...c0+c0-c 10c.c`? Try `(?<!\s\d*)0(?!\d*[+-])`

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cs%5cd*%290%28%3f!%5cd*%5b%5c%2b%5c-%5d%29&i=+0+0c000c0%2bc0-c+10c0c%0d%0a+100c+%3e%3e%3e++100c%0d%0ac00c10%2b+%3e%3e%3e+c..c10%2b%0d%0a+0+0cc0c0-+%3e%3e%3e++0+0cc.c0-&r=.), does it work as expected?

Comment: Yeah, that works as it should! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a *lookbehind*, not a lookahead. Use

```
(?<!\s\d*)0(?!\d*[+-])
^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cs%5Cd%2A%290%28%3F!%5Cd%2A%5B%5C%2B%5C-%5D%29&i=%200%200c000c0%2Bc0-c%2010c0c%0D%0A%20100c%20%3E%3E%3E%20%20100c%0D%0Ac00c10%2B%20%3E%3E%3E%20c..c10%2B%0D%0A%200%200cc0c0-%20%3E%3E%3E%20%200%200cc.c0-&r=.).

There is no need to use `+` after `\s` in the lookbehind, as a single whitespace check is enough.

Note there is no need to escape `+` in the character class and no need to escape `-` if it is at the end/start of the character class.

**Details**

- `(?<!\s\d*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a whitespace and 0+ digits immediately to the left of the current location
- `0` - a zero
- `(?!\d*[+-])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0+ digits followed with `-` or `+` immediately to the right of the current location.